# Continuous Running total in Excel Power Pivot

Tags: excel, dax

I would like to display/calculate my running total in pivot table in excel until the next year without resetting every other year.

Any workaround ideas to achieve my desired outcome?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this issue partially by Un-grouping the date fields. It worked for me like that.
This still doesn't work for the grouped date fields.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another turn around is to add field/s for the cumulative formula manually to the table, then show them in the pivot table while selecting "MAX" instead of "SUM" as the type of calculation.